# Building my 4k Ready VR Ready PC

Tags: pc, 4k

I would like to thank everyone who has taken the time to read and answer my questions. So I am building a computer VR-4K ready.[image: Everything I got it checked red.] https://pcpartpicker.com/list/KZjD6X I have checked everything I have gotten, only thing that is really bothering me is PSU, Tower, motherboard.

I want the best but I will not be overclocking, I never overclocked, not really interested unless it makes my gameplay better. Which I heard it can but still, I really want to buy these but maybe a professional can tell me otherwise. What I am looking for is to add a Samsung SSD Pro 960 1TB but maybe later in life maybe summer 2018. But for now everything I want is set.

Reason I want PSU is because I want it to be efficient, if you think there is a cheaper one but has the same efficiency let me know link it.

The reason I want the motherboard is because it seems to be the best and honestly the price makes me believe it is the best, but if you have a motherboard that's cheaper and does about the same, please link it.

The reason i wanted to get the Tower was because I saw a video on youtube saying it's highly customization and it's the best tower of 2017

but if you have a really easy to clean FULL TOWER that is better than this please let me know.

If it's better or just as good but cheaper, that's what is really important to me. if you can help me that would be great, the GPU is the final item I will buy, because is so expensive. but if you think the original is better than this please let me know.

Comment: Uh, what are you asking for?

Comment: For a cheaper Case, PSU, Mobo. :/

Comment: I have closed your question as it is too broad for our site. We expect questions to focus on only _one_ piece of hardware at a time. This allow the answerers to give you more details as to _why_ they are recommending the hardware. Because of this reason, we also do not allow build requests/reviews. Please break this question up into multiple questions, and you are encouraged to add link to the others.

Comment: This is just sad. I can't find a place to belong. I have looked everywhere posted everywhere and only 1 person gave me a good answer. anyway thanks you can close this account. bye.